# Screen does not dim Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lightdm, lock-screen

I've set blank screen after 1 minute but it does not blank. It keeps running. Maybe, it's because I turned off some services. Which one is related to blanking the screen? I use lightdm.

Disabled services:

```
bluetooth
apport
speech-dispatcher
unattended-upgrades
whoopsie
acpid
avahi-daemon
docker
hddtemp
openvpn
virtualbox
```

Comment: Wow... that's broad.  We don't know what services you've turned off; would you please [edit] to tell us which ones you have turned off?  Thanks!